# IBM 4690 supermarket application data file

Tags: file, transactions, format

I'm conducting a data analytics project for a small supermarket and the IT guy sent me a file (.db0 extension) of their transaction details, but I'm unable to read it.  Apparently it comes from the IBM 4690 Supermarket Application controller.  I've done internet searches and nothing helpful comes up.  The guy that sent it to me said he has never had to convert or read it into CSV or any other file format, so he can't provide any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

.dbo files are transaction sumary log file.

You can get info about file if you get the SA PROGRAMMING GUIDE look for transaction summary log.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I took so long to answer my question when I found a solution.  I'm sure it will help someone.

I Found a product called DataMiner from ValPOS (www.valpos.com) that did exactly what I wanted and more.  it creates an ODBC connection to the 4690 legacy files making it easy to read, query, and manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the TLOG backup file (DbO) file will be in binary format. Please use any of Hex Editor to view the contents of the file but before that you should be well versed about TLOG strings to understand the transaction details.